# What can cause cout << variable << "\t"; to print blankspace instead of a value, when the output exceeds terminal width?

Tags: c++, printing, console, terminal, cout

I have a series of three loops that each cout a row of `\t` delimited values

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct the_struct {
    float a_float;
    the_struct() :a_float(0){}
};

class the_class {public: the_struct a_struct;};

int main ()
{ 
    vector <the_class> v_objects;
    for(int q=0; q < 30; q++)
        v_objects.push_back(the_class());

    srand(0);
    int* int_dynamic_array = new int [30];
    for(int q=0; q < 30; q++)
        int_dynamic_array[q] = rand() % 30;

    for(int q=0; q < 30; q++)
        cout << q << "\t";
    cout << "\n";
    for(int q=0; q < 30; q++)
        cout << v_objects[q].a_struct.a_float << "\t";   //at runtime, these are all zeros
    cout << "\n";
    for(int q=0; q < 30; q++)
        cout << int_dynamic_array[q]  << "\t";           //random values between 0 and 29 
    cout << "\n";
}
```

For some reason, this code only prints exactly 11 values from the 2nd loop, and randomly omits between 0 and 4 values from the third loop. The first loop never has problems. For example (without tabs):

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29  
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   
4 7 2 9 7 4 3 1 6 5 26 12 8  28 13 11 22 7  19 2  26 13 9  12 15 24 8
```

Strangely, if I modify the tab string from `"\t"` to `"x\t"`, the program now outputs every value, but obviously with an x after each. For example:

```
0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x 0x
```

Comment: The type of `v_objects` and `v_objects[q]` here is rather vital information.

Comment: Not to mention how they have been initialized.

Comment: `v_objects` is a vector and `v_objects[q]` is an object/class

Comment: @Aasmund: What's the difference?

Comment: @Andr: you want me to define it?

Comment: @Matt Munson: Well, a common error is to fail to initialize some or all of the array values, or to create an array of the wrong size, leading to strange behaviour. The reason we'd like to see the full declarations is that the types that are involved can have an effect on how `<<` works.

Comment: @Aasmund: I will try to distill and post the relevant information from my code, which is too long to post in its entirety. But in any case, that still wouldn't explain the behavior with `int_dynamic_array[q]`

Comment: Please distill your program to the smallest complete example that demonstrates your problem. For more information about why that is important, and tips on how to do it, see http://sscce.org.

Comment: My theory: The code you are showing us is not the code that is executing on your computer and producing this output.  Something that you're doing wrong is fooling you into believing that this is the code you are executing, but it's not.  Just a guess though.

Comment: An additional reason, beyond those on the page Rob links to, is that if you knew which part of your code the bug was in, you wouldn't need to ask the likes of Stack Overflow, you'd just fix it. Since you don't know what part of your code is buggy, the probability that you've shown the part with the bug in it is approximately equal to the proportion of your code that you've shown ;-p

Comment: @Aasmund: I have added compileable code that produces the error.

Comment: Can't reproduce using GCC on Cygwin, although I note that 11 zeroes is exactly what fits in a single line of the terminal. Coincidence, or some problem with how you're viewing it? What happens if you redirect to a file?

Comment: @Benjamin: Here's the full code

Comment: @Steve It outputs fine to a file if I use ofstream instead of cout. However, cout works fine if I replace `cout << v_objects[q].a_struct.a_float << "\t";` with `cout << q << "\t";` and do the same for 3rd loop.

Comment: But if the 11th value is single-digit (which 0 is), then you're outputting a tab when the terminal is exactly on the line-end. If the 11th value is two digits (which 10 is, so is 0x), then at least on my terminal the tab stops are set such that the 10 breaks across the line, so the tab character isn't at line-end. Obviously this *shouldn't* be a problem, I just have a hunch that it might be. By "redirect" I actually meant via the shell with `>`, then check the file by some means other than sending it to terminal, e.g. `wc`. So you're still using `cout`, just viewing the output a different way.

Comment: @Steve AHA!! You're right. I'v been executing from my GUI and terminal always opens with the same dimensions. I opened terminal, adjusted the terminal dimensions, and then ran from the prompt and it worked fine. I can also modulate where the cutoff occurs in the same manner. Seems like a pretty significant flaw for the default mac terminal. Anyways, why don't you add your solution as an answer and I'll accept it. Should I also change the question title to reflect the relevant parameters of the problem? Thanks allot for your help :)

Comment: @Matt: maybe change the question title a bit, but don't change it so much that it answers the question itself, that defeats the purpose of having a serchable Q/A archive :-) Mention that it's tab at end-of-line, maybe. Btw, what happens if you output `0\t` ten times, then `0\t`, then `123`? Do you see `123` at the start of the line you've just printed, like `123 0 0 ...`? If so, it seems the tab has (in old-school terminal lingo) caused a CR instead of a CRLF.

Comment: @Steve You mean doing `cout << "0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t" << "0\t" << "123";`? This does not cause that effect. It just makes the `123` get cut in half; the `23` is displayed on the next line.

Comment: @Matt: Hmm. You'd think the 11th `0` would be on the last space of that line, as before, but you're saying the `1` of `123` is. So the 11th `0` has been overwritten, as if the offending 11th tab has in fact moved the cursor back one space (to the last tab stop of the current line), instead of moving on to the first space of the next line. How about a `sleep` between the 11th `0\t` and the `123` - do you see that `0` appear, then get blatted?

Comment: @Steve If I do `cout << "0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t" << "0\t" <<sleep(10) << "123";` Then there's a pause and then everything shows up at once, except there are 11 zeros on the first line, and `123` on the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in comments under the question, this seems to be a bug/quirk in the Mac terminal (I'm thinking bug, but I don't know if the Posix spec says something weird about the allowable interaction between tabs and the right-hand-side of the terminal).

If the 11th value is single-digit (which 0 is), then at least on my terminal the tab stops are set such that you're outputting a tab when the terminal is exactly on the line-end. If the 11th value is two digits[*], then it breaks across the line, so the tab character isn't at line-end. Obviously this *shouldn't* be a problem, I just have a hunch that it might be.

I don't see the same result on my terminal (which isn't Mac, it's actually puttycyg on Windows) - for me outputting that tab moves the cursor to the next line, as you'd expect.

[*] Which 10 is, so is 0x, and so is 26, the 11th value you get out of `rand() % 30` on your machine having seeded with `srand(0)`

Answer (score 1):

Although the problem seems to be about output, there may be another case which should be considered.

Here at v_objects[q], if v_objects is an instance of a class which overloaded [] operator that takes a reference to int, the value of q may be incremented/changed there which will cause for loop to be exited earlier than you expected.

for example:

```
some_type operator[] ( int &a )
{
    // a can be incremented here
    a++;
}
```

As you did not give the full source, we can not find the cause exactly.

Comment: Wow, way to think outside the box! Possible, but who on earth would implement `operator[]` to automatically increment the index?

Comment: @Praetorian maybe accidentally :)

Comment: @Mustafa: Well `v_objects` is a std::vector. So I think it does overload [], but I don't think there's any chance that it will change the value in q.

Answer (score 1):

the outputs are there, this is the problem with the command line output screen,
if you just do

$ ./a.out > op.txt

and open the output file, you will see the output is very much there.

Also if you change the tab spacing to the new line

"\t" to "\n", then also you can see the output on screen.

But i agree there is some problem with the command line output screen when using the tab delimiter

EDIT:

The problem is with the size of the console window.

for size 62*40,
number of zeros = 9

for size 90*40,
number of zeros = 13

for size 120*40,
number of zeros = 16

for size 150*40,
number of zeros = 20

and using both my monitors, i get all of them...

for size 260*40,
number of zeros = 30

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot the `std::endl` or `std::flush` at the end of the output. Simply outputing `` `\n' `` is not enough to flush the output, so you'll end with a short output.

The case when adding the `x` will work may be caused by the internal buffer to be full (and then output) because the `x` increase the size of the output to a limit that causes the output of the current buffer (not happening when the buffer is shorter without the `x`.)

**EDIT**:

As the author of the question says it does not work with flushing, then, the only thing that comes to my mind is that some of those fields are characters or strings thay may be empty, or have been unadvertedly filled with spaces. (This is why it is important that you show the definition of those types).

Comment: neither `<<endl` and/or `<<flush` fixes the problem

Comment: @Diego Sevilla: As long as it was opened in text mode, writing a "\n" to a stream is portable. The compiler will replace the newline character with whatever is appropriate for that platform.

Comment: @Matt: OK, then, the only thing that comes to my mind is that some of those fields are characters or strings thay may be empty, or have been filled with spaces.

Comment: @Diego: the variable in loop 2 is a float, and in loop 3 is an int, so I don't think that that is possible.